# Altium Designer space bar doesn't rotate components

Tags: altium

I am having a strange behaviour in Altium 14. When I place a component on the PCB in PCB Editor, if I press space bar, instead of rotating the component by 90°, it only opens a dialog where I have to enter the number of degrees by which I want to turn the component -- this is very annoying.

I have already checked the PCB Editor Preferences in DXP Preferences and the rotation step is already set to 90°, but still it asks me how much I want to rotate every single time I press space bar...

I also found that pressing `L` opens the View configurations instead of flipping components.

Any idea how to change this?

PS: I have already tried to reset the default settings from the Preferences, still without success.

Comment: Have you tried closing the program ? Altium is like Windows. When it doesnt work, restart.

Comment: I've not got a copy of Altium on this computer but from what I remember, if you go into preferences and click PCB Editor, then under 'Other' it should have the rotation step amount, if this is blank then I assume that is why it is asking you each time. Just check this is set to 90

Comment: @Hayman I've tried to blank out the rotation step, but it defaults back to whatever it was before. I am on Altium 16, so maybe this was changed. OP give it a shot.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to close altium and to restart it, i even tried to open a new project, with same result.

Comment: My rotation step is set to 90 so normally it shoudl rotate automatically, but it doesn't.

Comment: I have to mention that rotation of component works fine in the schematic part of altium. This is only in the PCB editor that it doesn't work

Comment: Going to make a guess on this one. In the schematic you can simply select a part and hit the spacebar and it rotates. In the PCB editor the part has to be "floating" in order to rotate it, meaning you have to click and hold it (as if to drag) with the mouse, and then hit the spacebar while "holding" it. The same goes for flipping the component (X-Y), etc.

Comment: @derstrom8 : you are right it work !!! Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @chris That's great to hear! I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Going to make a guess on this one. In the schematic you can simply select a part and hit the spacebar and it rotates. In the PCB editor the part has to be "floating" in order to rotate it, meaning you have to click and hold it (as if to drag) with the mouse, and then hit the spacebar while "holding" it. The same goes for flipping the component (X-Y), etc.

Answer (score 0):

1.Edit>move>Rotate selection

2.Ctrl+Left Click mouse

3.Edit command change "R" to "Spacebare"

4.Ok

As shown in the screenshots below
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did have exact this problem, andf solved it doing this:
Tools > Preferences > System > View > Desktop > Reset

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Preferences > PCB Editor > General
then set Rotation Step = 90.

As shown in the screenshots below
[image]